# wso2 emm 500: Something has gone wrong

Tags: java, wso2

After general server configuration i'm able to log in to carbon, store or publisher without any issue with default admin login.

Unfortunately when i sign in EMM: https://myserver:port/emm -> sso/login

i end up in /emm/acs - "500: Something has gone wrong" page.

Debug: 2 errors in live terminal:

```
*[2015-06-12 20:35:21,254] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.hostobjects.xhr.XMLHttpRequestHostObject} -  Connection refused java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused*

*[2015-06-12 20:35:21,261] ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -        org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (http#220)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (http#220)*
```

And i got another 2 errors after wso2server startup:

```
*[2015-06-12 21:44:34,231] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent} -  Error in initializing thrift transport
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not bind to port 10397*

*[2015-06-12 21:44:34,247] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceComponent} -  Failed to initialize key management service.
java.lang.Exception: Error in initializing thrift transport*
```

Any hints?

Regards,

Lukas

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with the /emm/acs redirection issue, actually I don't know why it has been happening, but when it happens, I do a refresh on the page, everything works fine.

The second issue you have mentioned, is nothing to do with the first one, it says that Apache Thrift Transport layer could not bind the port. Since EMM does not require Thrift, you can simply disable by editing the following XML configuration files.

Change true to false for the following config files, under the target folder.

```
./repository/conf/api-manager.xml:280:  <EnableThriftServer>true</EnableThriftServer>
./repository/conf/identity.xml:218:            <EnableThriftService>true</EnableThriftService>
```

Comment: Thank you, trift disabled and startup logs are clear now.

Comment: Issue with emm login still persists "java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused". Btw only port i have open from the public atm is 9443.